# Using [Bind(Prefix="xyz")] at controller level?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a standard set of routes, used across controllers, such as {controller}/{action}/{clientId}/{id}. All controllers are using each of these values, but each controller may use {id} in a different context.

For example, an {id} on a LabController may be "labId", and {id} on MembershipController may be "membershipId", etc. Instead of using "id" in every action method on each controller, I'd like to pass in "labId" and "membershipId" as parameters for actions in their respective controllers.

I could use [Bind(Prefix="id")] for every single action, but I was hoping there could be a way to control it at the controller level. I'm also trying to avoid multiple (nearly identical) routes for similar paths. Thanks.

EDIT: to clarify, I'm trying to bind these to parameters on my actions. Such as:

```
public ActionResult GetLab(int labId)
```

or

```
public ActionResult GetMembership(int membershipId)
```

All using the same route - just binding the {id} part as an alias for, in these cases, labId and membershipId, without having to use [Bind] every time.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to bind a parameter name to the route at all. Keep in mind that the generic "id" parameter name is just a placeholder for the passed in value. So your routes become:

```
Lab/SomeAction/1
```

and

```
Membership/SomeAction/1
```

It doesn't care what the paramter name is in this case. You are thinking more in terms of query string parameters and not route parameters.

Comment: The values in the route dictionary have names, though, that map to parameters on my actions. Meaning, {labId} maps to a "int labId" on my action, as does {membershipId} maps to "int membershipId" on another action. The routes are all the same pattern (controller/action/clientid/id), but I want to be able to map "id" to different names depending on the controller so that I'm not having to use [Bind] for every case.